# MAX471 current sensor minimum current measurement

Tags: current-measurement

I'm trying to use a [MAX471 module](http://www.ebay.com/itm/MAX471-DC3V-25V-Voltage-Current-Test-Sensor-Module-for-Arduino-/182210585285?hash=item2a6c98e2c5:g:6CEAAOSwsFpWRTCA) (no brand) with arduino (5V) following this [tutorial](http://henrysbench.capnfatz.com/henrys-bench/arduino-projects-tips-and-more/arduino-max471-power-meter-tutorial/).

I measure the current with my multimeter of a motor with a 200Ω resistor and i get ~14.84mA. The sensor displays ~13.8mA and some times it drops to ~8.6mA

I power the motor with Arduino as power supply via the module.

When I connect instead of a motor a LED via a 1k resistor, i get 2.80mA in the multimeter the sensor displays 0. Does it have a minimum range and can this be fixed so to get current sensing for low current?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Datasheet](http://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX471-MAX472.pdf) on the IC, the accuracy drops to 15% at 1% full scale current.  Full scale is 3A, 1% is 30mA.  So you definitely need a better current sensor.

Comment: The fact that the module is an Ebay cheapie based on an obsolete part from a prolifically faked manufacturer adds weight to your advice!